# Wait script overrides default CMD and exits Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, wait

Docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: localhost
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
      MYSQL_USER: mysql
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 1234
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    expose:
      - 3307
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/migrations:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    restart: unless-stopped
  web:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: web/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./:/web
    ports:
      - "32768:3000"
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: development
      PORT: 3000
    links:
      - mysql:mysql
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    expose:
      - 3000
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "mysql:3306", "--", "npm start"]
```

Web Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6.11.2-slim

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD [ "npm", "start" ] # So this is overridden by the wait script and doesn't execute
```

I'm using this wait script:
https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it

The wait script works fine, however it overrides the existing start command for the web container:
`CMD [ "npm", "start" ]`

As you can see in the docker-compose file I'm using this approach to kick off npm start:
`command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "mysql:3306", "--", "npm start"]`

I have tried a few alternative e.g:
`command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "mysql:3306", "--", "CMD ['npm', 'start'"]`
`command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "mysql:3306", "--", "docker-entrypoint.sh"]`

Only it is not working. I get this error from the web container:
`web_1    | ./wait-for-it.sh: line 174: exec: npm start: not found`

What's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all if you use `command` in `docker-compose` then it will override the the CMD and that is an expected behavior. How can docker know you want to execute both of them.

Next your approach is a bit wrong with the CMD

```
command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "mysql:3306", "--", "npm start"]
```

translates to you executing

```
./wait-for-it.sh mysql:3306 -- "npm start"
```

Which is supposed to fail as there is no command `npm start` it is `npm` which takes start as the argument. So change the command to

```
command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "mysql:3306", "--", "npm", "start"]
```

or

```
command: ./wait-for-it.sh mysql:3306" -- npm start
```

Whichever format you like

Comment: Dang! I was so close. Got rid of the CMD in the Dockerfile and adjusted the command arg in docker-compose. Works perfectly. Thanks!