# postgres & docker compose: change service status to ready after additional initialization

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

In my case, a postgres database works as the main django backend database. Additional postgres initialization is required. The problem is that status of `postgres` service becomes `ready` before additional database initialization. As a result, dependent django app starts running prior to database initialization.

Is there any way to configure `postgres` service in a way that becomes `ready` after additional initialization?

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  postgres:
    image: library/postgres:11
    volumes:
      - some_folder:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

  django_app:
    image: custom_django_image:latest
    volumes:
      - $PWD:/app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

Comment: You could use a script such as this in https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/. Before running Django you could check if your database is in the expected state.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45455037/wait-script-overrides-default-cmd-and-exits-docker-container/45458049#45458049

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `some_folder`, which is mapped to the Postgres container's `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` location is where you (and seems like you are doing) should place your initialization scripts. As long as there is no data in a 
 possible volume attached to the Postgres container's `/var/lib/postgresql/data` directory (persisting data), upon container creation, Postgres will first run those scripts before setting Postgres to a `ready` state. The scripts must be either `.sh` or `.sql` files. ([documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres)). I'll show a typical workflow I use:

I have this script which creates multiple databases:

```sh
# create-multiple-databases.sh

set -e
set -u

function create_user_and_database() {
    local database=$1
    echo "  Creating user and database '$database'"
    psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" <<-EOSQL
        CREATE USER $database;
        CREATE DATABASE $database;
        GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE $database TO $database;
EOSQL
}

if [ -n "$POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES" ]; then
    echo "Multiple database creation requested: $POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES"
    for db in $(echo $POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES | tr ',' ' '); do
        create_user_and_database $db
    done
    echo "Multiple databases created"
fi
```

In the `docker-compose.yml` file I set:

```yaml
environment:
  - POSTGRES_MULTIPLE_DATABASES=dev,test
```

Now when running `docker-compose up`, I see the output from the script, and then finally:

```sh
postgres_1            | CREATE DATABASE
postgres_1            | GRANT
postgres_1            | Multiple databases created
...
postgres_1            | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
postgres_1            |
postgres_1            | 2020-05-23 16:18:40.055 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 12.2 (Debian 12.2-2.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0, 64-bit
postgres_1            | 2020-05-23 16:18:40.056 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1            | 2020-05-23 16:18:40.056 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1            | 2020-05-23 16:18:40.063 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
```

Now inside my Django application, in a typical `settings.py` file (or similar related settings file), I create a while loop that only completes once that database is ready. Once completed, the Django server continues its initialization process and then starts running the server.

```py
while True:
    from django.db import connections
    from django.db.utils import OperationalError
    conn = connections["default"]  # or some other key in `DATBASES`
    try:
        c = conn.cursor()
        LOGGER.info("Postgres Ready")
        break
    except OperationalError:
        LOGGER.warning("Postgres Not Ready...")
        time.sleep(0.5)
```

Providing I have understood your question, I hope this gives you the information needed in your question.

Comment: IMO, I would suggest using healthchecks of docker-compose.yml instead of doing code changes in the app itself

Comment: From my exp: In your answer using `depends_on`, does not wait for the DB to be ready, but the service itself, assuming that the OP's entry point starts the server, if the DB is not ready, the main process for the container will fail and kill the container, `restart: always`? yes, but vague as to what went wrong. The same goes for `healthcheck`, the Django server doesn't know the health of the DB container. My services tend to have a lot of dependencies/DB's, the approach that has always worked well for me is by logging and writing code to 'preflight-check' before starting the server.

Comment: I wouldn't agree with the approach, as that's why healthchecks are defined and depends_on. If you configure both in a right manner, then this works and that's what their use is

Comment: That's fine, it's up to the OP which approach they want to use, I believe the OP's question was about running DB initialization scripts before the DB became ready anyway. I added the code that checks for answer completeness. I do it my way because I want pretty much the same code-base and the same logic for when running in docker, outside docker, serverless, etc. Coding such logic in the application is just what works for my use cases.

Answer (score 3):

I would highly suggest looking at **health checks** of `docker-compose.yml`. 
You can change the `healthcheck` command to specific postgresql check, Once health-check is ready, then only djano will start sending the request to the postgresql container.

Please consider using the below file.

```
version: "3.3"

services:
  postgres:
    image: library/postgres:11
    volumes:
      - some_folder:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

  django_app:
    image: custom_django_image:latest
    volumes:
      - $PWD:/app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

> Ref:- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#healthcheck

Comment: Came here to suggest this. IMO, startup dependency health-checks, like the Django app trying to connect to the DB before anything else, should be done by whatever is bringing the processes up in the first place, and not in code. The host/scheduler should have the tools to make the checks. In your case, you're using containers and `docker-compose`, which already supports this with `depends_on`, and `healthcheck`. I think this makes for cleaner app code and semantics: your app isn't _failing_, the other systems aren't ready yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at how Django Cookiecutter Template does it: https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django

What they do here is use a startup script for production using Docker: [here](https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/compose/production/django/entrypointhttps://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_slug%7D%7D/compose/production/django/entrypoint)

This entrypoint script checks, whether postgres is up and running and only proceeds then, otherwise it loops over the connection. You can write a similar script based on that snippet to check, whether your postgres instance is up and running correctly. Whether it is ready or not you can decide in your script `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`. It should do all the operations it requires. Once it's done, you can startup postgres and the script for Django should then proceed because it can reach the postgres instance.

It works well for me, I do some other checks in the `entrypoint` script before I proceed to starting the server itself.